# I'm trying to Update Key Vault secret using Set-AzKeyVaultSecret cmdlet in PowerShell script. It is creating new version of secret

Tags: powershell, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to Update Key Vault secret using Set-AzKeyVaultSecret cmdlet in PowerShell script. It is creating new version of secret even when there is no change in secret name or value. My requirement is to update the secret value and version only if there is any change is secret value. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [Get-AzKeyVaultSecret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-8.1.0) to check the value first, then set only when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Secrets are immutable (you can't update secret) so any update create new version of the secret by design.

Answer (score 0):

use [Update-AzKeyVaultSecret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/update-azkeyvaultsecret?view=azps-10.1.0) instead